Understanding Quantum Harmonic Oscillator with Piecewise Potential
I just got out of an exam today, and have been wrestling with one of the questions.
I was given a simple (quantum) 1D harmonic oscillator, with potential given by:
$${V(x)=\infty, \forall x<0}$$
$$V(x)=(\frac{1}{2}m\omega^{2}x^{2}), \forall x\ge 0$$
The question called for me to sketch the wave function $\psi(x)$ for the oscillator at its ground state, and compare the ground-state energy to that for the same oscillator without the potential spike.
I know what the basic graph sketches look like for the "normal" potential and wave function, but I'm completely puzzled on how $\psi(x)$ would look in this case, or even how one would derive a new expression for it.
Many thanks in advance for any advice you all can offer!

This was asked here before, for sure.

"I was given a simple... 1D harmonic oscillator." No. A simple 1D harmonic oscillator is effectively defined by its potential being $\propto x^2$ everywhere. The potential you have proposed is not $\propto x^2$ everywhere. What you should be Googling for is "half harmonic oscillator"

Do you understand what $\psi$ has to be at $x=0$?

This is a standard exercise - try using the solutions of the non-truncated oscillator.

Duplicate.

This question is similar to: Question regarding the half Harmonic Oscillator. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If we write down the Schrodinger equation, it has the same form as that for a harmonic oscillator for $x\geq 0$ (i.e., satisfied by the same solutions), but the boundary condition at $x=0$ is that at the infinite potential wall, $\psi(0)=0$. That is of all the solutions of HO we need to choose the ones, satisfying this bc.
